# File not found exception when attempting to validate xml against xsd file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I keep getting File Not Found exception when I try to run the following code:

```
public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
    try{
        SchemaFactory factory =
                SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
        javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is how I'm calling my method:

```
Boolean value = validateXMLSchema("shiporder.xsd",xmlfile);
```

shiporder is the name of the file that the compiler looks for in the project folder.

The xmlfile variable is a string containing the xml file which will be compared against the xds file.

I'm getting a file not found exception even though I've checked the location of the file is correct.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

This is the xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this issue?

Comment: What do `new File(xmlPath).exists()` and `new File(xsdPath).exists()` return? (Also the full stack trace would be helpful.) If one of the above returns `false`, then you have your problem - if that's the case, print out the relevant file's `getAbsolutePath()` and check the difference between that and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You're not telling the File() constructor where the file is.  This constructor will resolve the filename to an abstract pathname and resolve the result against a system-dependent default directory.  That's probably not what you want.

If the xsd is somewhere in your project, use `yourProject.YourReader.class.getResource(xsdPath)`.  xsdPath will be a "relative" resource name, which is treated relative to the class's package. Alternatively you can specify an "absolute" resource name by using a leading slash.  For example, if your xsd is in the same directory as its reader, use `getResource("shiporder.xsd")`.  If you are going from the project root, use `getResource("/path/to/shiporder.xsd")`.

You can then turn this resource into a File, if you need to, by using `new File(resource.toURI())`

For your code:

```
    public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
           try{
                SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
                Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(ThisClass.class.getResource("/path/to/shiporder.xsd").toURI());
                ...
    }}
```